# Load HMTL5 Audio on click (not before, to increase pagespeed)

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio

I would like the audio source to load on click and not on page load to increase pagespeed. How could I do this?

If its not above the fold I just could wrap it into an iframe and then it would lazyload. But thats not a solution for above the fold audios.

```html
<audio id="music" controls="controls" preload="none">
<source src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/355309/Swing_Jazz_Drum.mp3" type="audio/ogg" />
<source src="music/onlyidreamwithyou1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

Comment: Are you saying `preload="none"` is not already doing that? When I tested it in Chrome looking at the Network tab in the dev tools I don't see any loading until I press play

Comment: youre right... didnt know that. It must be sth on our site, that is causing to load that audio anyway.